# Android-value not able to set in textview

Tags: android, textview

I have a SQLite database **add2cart** which stores details of products added to cart.I need to display the number of products each user have in their cart,in a text view. **crtno** is my textview.I want to display the number in textview when each user clicks add2cart button.

**code**

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.product_dtls);

    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPr_name);
    price = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtprice);
    specification=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtPr_spec);
    feature=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtPr_feature);

    crtno=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.crtno);

    add2cart=(Button)findViewById(R.id.add2cart);

    DataBaseHandler dbh = new DataBaseHandler(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbh.getWritableDatabase();
    Intent in = getIntent();
    Bundle bn = in.getExtras();
    Bundle bun=in.getExtras();
    final String dtl=bun.getString("key");
    nme = bn.getString("name");

    Cursor cr = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM product WHERE pname = '"+nme+"'", null);

    while(cr.moveToNext())
    {
        String name = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("pname"));
        String pr1price = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("pprice"));
        String prspc=cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("pspec"));
        String prfeature=cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("pfeature"));
        pname = name;
        prprice = pr1price;
        pspec=prspc;
        pfeature=prfeature;
    }
    name.setText(pname);
    price.setText("Rs " +prprice + "/-");
    specification.setText(pspec);
    feature.setText(pfeature);


    add2cart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            boolean incart=false;
            String nm=name.getText().toString();

            mydb=Product_Details.this.openOrCreateDatabase("addcart", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            mydb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS add2cart(usr TEXT,img BLOB,pnme TEXT,prate NUMERIC,pqty NUMERIC,ptotl NUMERIC)");
            Cursor cur=mydb.rawQuery("select * from add2cart where pnme='"+nm+"' AND usr='"+dtl+"'",null);

            if (cur.moveToFirst()){
                String prdname=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("pnme"));

                if (nm.equals(prdname)){
                    add2cart.setText("Already in Cart");
                    incart=true;
                }
            }

            if(incart==false){
                mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO add2cart (usr,pnme,prate)VALUES('"+dtl+"','"+nm+"','"+prprice+"')");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"added to cart",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Cursor crsr=mydb.rawQuery("select pnme from add2cart where usr='"+dtl+"'", null);



//                  int count=0;
           Boolean val=false;
           int  count=crsr.getCount();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"count"+count, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
crtno.setText(Integer.toString(count));
//             abc=crtno.getText().toString();
                if (crtno!=null) {
                                    val=true;                       
                    crtno.setText(Integer.toString(count));
                }
                if (val=false) {
                crtno.setText("0");


                }

            }


        }
    });
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: First tell me how you decide how many items are added in cart.(its count)

Comment: yes.I am getting number from cursor.getcount and assign to count. and if textview ,crtno is null set '0' .if not null set count

Comment: according to your code its not adding item in cart second time

Comment: if (cur.moveToFirst()){
                String prdname=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("pnme"));

                if (nm.equals(prdname)){
                    add2cart.setText("Already in Cart");
                    incart=true;
                }
            }

Comment: ok. so you are getting int  count=crsr.getCount(); in this. Are you sure you are getting accurate count

Comment: @paypaluser: what problem you are getting?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I am getting the count correctly.But not able to set it into textview.It causes nullpoint exception.So I wrote null check code.So now there is no error but count not displaying in textview

Comment: @paypaluser: where you are initializing `crtno` using findviewbyId ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK in oncreate.I have included that part of code.

Comment: @paypaluser: ok are you sure `crtno` TextView is in `product_dtls.xml` file?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK sorry.I initialised it with wrong id..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change condition.(make sure you have done above on click listner crtno = findviewbyId....)

```
if(count != null && count > 0){

   crtno.setText(count+"");

}else{

  crtno.setText("0");
}
```

Comment: It caused null pointer exception in line -  crtno.setText(count+"");

Comment: are you sure you have find id of crtno

Comment: I am sorry.I initialised it with another id.sorry for wasting your time..Thanks for your valuable time.